# Current user for apps in Microsoft OneDrive API

Tags: rest, api, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The SDKs for other cloud storage providers (e.g., `Google Drive`, `Dropbox`, `Box`) offer an option to retrieve the "current" (signed-in) user.

The same applies for `Microsoft OneDrive`, via the `Microsoft Graph API` (via calling `GET /me`). However, for applications getting an accessToken via clientId and clientSecret, that API does not work.

Is there any "current" user for such cases?

Comment: Such a token has no user context, and so there's no way for the system to know who `me` represents. A token with application permissions can still access user content, but you'll need to address the target user specifically.

Comment: I expected the answer based on my findings until asking the question, but asked in the hope that I was still missing something. Anyway, fair is fair. +1 and accepted. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting an access token via clientId and clientSecret(client credentials flow), you will not be able to call `GET/me`. However, you can call `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to get a user if you have granted your app **User.Read.All** permission.

If you want to call `GET/me`, you need to [get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).